# Is there a way to "try parse" a string to System.Globalization.CultureInfo

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

In C#, I am using

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(myCulture)
```

but the string variable may not come in a good format, is there a way to try parse the string first or verify it first.

Comment: tryParse what ? to `int`

Comment: @Habib As he writes in the title, he wants to parse a `string` into a `CultureInfo`.

Comment: @UweKeim, now seeing the answer the question becomes more clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following yields a collection of all cultures:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
```

From there, rather than `GetCultureInfo` you could do:

```
.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == myCulture)
```

Rather than `AllCultures` you may want to filter out [`SpecificCultures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.culturetypes.aspx).

Comment: You can even pick up all cultures in a `Dictionary<,>` if this is something you do all the time. As in: `static readonly Dictionary<string, CultureInfo> CultureDict = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).ToDictionary(c => c.Name);`

Answer (score -1):

there is no tryparse with culture objects. one way is to go through all cultures as suggested and look for one and the other way is to use the simple try parse:

```
try
{
    // making sure the lang is a calture
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
}
catch
{
    lang = Session["lang"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: You should never ever do some thing like this! change `catch` to `catch(CultureNotFoundException ex)`.

Answer (score -3):

I always use a little helper in my project. All arithmetic types got TryParse method

```
public static bool TryParseDouble(this string text, out double value)
{
   return double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any,
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);
}
```

The usage

```
double value;
bool isStringOK = theString.TryParseDouble(out value);
```

Comment: So what does `double` have to do with `CultureInfo` as the original poster asks?