# Web.API - how to validate performant list of languages based on CultureInfo

Tags: c#, performance, validation, cultureinfo

I'm working with Web.API/.Net 7 and need to validate and conform a list of `language ranges` coming from `Accept-Language` header. The langauge ranges should be checked against the list of possible `CultureInfo.Name` options. Language ranges must not adhere to lower and upper case writings. So in case of a match the correctly formatted  `CultureInfo.Name` should be used.

In [Is there a way to "try parse" a string to System.Globalization.CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345614/is-there-a-way-to-try-parse-a-string-to-system-globalization-cultureinfo) the recommended option for validation is to use `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)`.

One can use LINQ `Find()` to find a matching element. Even `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)` returns a sorted list of names already, it won't help much for `Find()`.

I think that there is a more performant solution than to scan 800+ entries of `CultureInfos` for each language in the `Accept-Language` header on each request.

In the above post it was recommended to put all elements in a dictionary and search that.

```
static readonly Dictionary<string, CultureInfo> CultureDict = 
    CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).ToDictionary(c => c.Name);
```

Would a `SortedList` with `BinarySearch` also be an option?

How can I load that `Dictionary` or `SortedList` into memory only one time and access it from all requests? Do I need a Singleton? Are there any issues with parallel read access?

I only have  basic understanding of those specifics, but what are the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary you have is the best option:

1. It is a constant O(1) operation to do a lookup
2. It is already declared as a static variable so it gets reused as a singleton

You could declare the dictionary via an interface and inject the dependency so it is available in your validation classes.

For example:

```
public interface ISingleton {
    Dictionary<string, CultureInfo> Instance { get; }
}

service.AddSingleton<ISingleton>(() => new Singleton {Instance = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).ToDictionary(c => c.Name)});
```

The one benefit with using dependency injection is your classes no longer depend on static properties and this makes things more reusable and testable.

Comment: I just realized that the search in the dictionary is not case sensitive, which is needed. This should do the work: .ToDictionary(c => c.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: I don't need the `CultureInfos`, just the `Name` property to validate the languages. This should do it: `Dictionary<string, string> _allLanguageTags = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Select(x => x.Name).ToDictionary(c => c, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: Nice catch. Yes, I generally recommend case insensitive lookup tables unless there is a specific reason not to do this.